# C++: SIGTRAP error in custrom String class

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I have scoured the internet for the past two days and can find no reason for this to be occurring.

My string class works in the way one would expect: it starts with an initial block of contiguous memory on the heap (128 bytes), and then resizes if need be.

All of my calls to `new` are matched with a *single* call to `delete[]` on the corresponding pointer.

The SIGTRAP error only occurs as the destructor is being called (which uses `delete[]` a final time).

In order to produce a minimal reproducible example, I have reduced the code (about 1400 lines) to what is seen below (and what seems to be causing the error).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

static int MIN_SIZE = 128;

    char *setchr_c(char *str, const char ch, size_t pos) {
        if (str == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        *(str + pos) = ch;
        return str;
    }

    class String {
    private:
        char *data = nullptr;
        char *string = nullptr;
        size_t length_w_null = 0;
        size_t size = 0;
        size_t space_front = 0;
        size_t space_back = 0;
        bool is_empty = true;

        void set_size(bool def_do = true) {
            if (def_do) {
                do {
                    size *= 2;
                } while (size < length_w_null);
                return;
            }
            while (size < length_w_null) {
                size *= 2;
            }
        }

        void constructor(const char *str, bool after_empty = false) {
            size = MIN_SIZE;
            length_w_null = strlen(str) + 1;
            set_size(false);
            if (after_empty) { // this is to avoid re-assigning the memory if not necessary
                if (size != MIN_SIZE) {
                    // free(data);
                    printf("CTOR AFTER EMPTY DELETE, DELETING: %x\n", data);
                    delete[] data;
                    // data = (char *) malloc(size);
                    printf("CTOR AFTER EMPTY NEW, SIZE: %llu, ", size);
                    data = new char[size];
                    printf("ADDRESS: %x\n", data);
                }
            } else {
                // data = (char *) malloc(size);
                printf("CTOR ELSE NEW, SIZE: %llu, ", size);
                data = new char[size];
                printf("ADDRESS: %x\n", data);
            }
            memset(data, '\0', size);
            string = data + get_first_pos();
            setchr_c(string, '\0', length_w_null - 1);
            strcpy(string, str);
            space_front = get_first_pos();
            space_back = is_even(length_w_null) ? space_front : space_front + 1;
            is_empty = false;
        }

        void empty_constructor() {
            // data = (char *) malloc(MIN_SIZE);
            printf("EMPTY CTOR NEW, MINSIZE: %llu, ", MIN_SIZE);
            data = new char[MIN_SIZE];
            printf("ADDRESS: %x\n", data);
            memset(data, '\0', size);
            string = nullptr;
            length_w_null = 0;
            size = MIN_SIZE;
            space_front = MIN_SIZE / 2;
            space_back = MIN_SIZE / 2;
            is_empty = true;
        }

        static bool is_even(size_t num) {
            return num % 2 == 0;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] unsigned long get_first_pos() const {
            size_t new_len = length_w_null;
            if (!is_even(new_len)) {
                new_len++;
            }
            unsigned long pos = size / 2 - (new_len) / 2;
            return pos;
        }

    public:
        static const size_t nopos = -1;
        String() {
            empty_constructor();
        }

        String(char ch) {
            if (ch == '\0') {
                empty_constructor();
            } else {
                const char str[2]{ch, '\0'};
                constructor(str);
            }
        }

        String(const char *str) {
            if (str == nullptr) {
                return;
            }
            if (strlen(str) == 0) {
                empty_constructor();
            } else {
                constructor(str);
            }
        }

        void append_back(const char *str) {
            if (str == nullptr) {
                return;
            }
            if (is_empty) {
                constructor(str, true);
                return;
            }
            size_t l = strlen(str);
            size_t old_l = length_w_null - 1;
            length_w_null += l;
            if (l + 1 > space_back) {
                set_size();
                char *old_data = data;
                char *old_str = string;
                // data = (char *) malloc(size);
                printf("APPEND BACK NEW, SIZE: %llu, ", size);
                data = new char[size];
                printf("ADDRESS: %x\n", data);
                memset(data, '\0', size);
                string = data + get_first_pos();
                strcpy(string, old_str);
                // free(old_data);
                printf("APPEND BACK DELETE OLD_DATA, DELETING: %x\n", old_data);
                delete[] old_data;
                space_front = get_first_pos();
                space_back = is_even(length_w_null) ? space_front : space_front + 1;
            }
            strcpy(string + old_l, str);
            space_back -= l;
        }

        void append_front(const char *str) {
            if (str == nullptr) {
                return;
            }
            if (is_empty) {
                constructor(str, true);
                return;
            }
            size_t l = strlen(str);
            length_w_null += l;
            char gone = *string;
            if (l > space_front) {
                set_size();
                char *old_data = data;
                char *old_str = string;
                // data = (char *) malloc(size);
                printf("APPEND FRONT NEW, SIZE: %llu, ", size);
                data = new char[size];
                printf("ADDRESS: %x\n", data);
                memset(data, '\0', size);
                string = data + get_first_pos();
                strcpy(string + l, old_str);
                // free(old_data);
                printf("APPEND FRONT DELETE OLD_DATA, DELETING: %x\n", old_data);
                delete[] old_data;
                strcpy(string, str);
                space_front = get_first_pos();
                space_back = is_even(length_w_null) ? space_front : space_front + 1;
            } else {
                strcpy(string - l, str);
                string -= l;
                space_front -= l;
            }
            setchr_c(string, gone, l);
        }

        void push_back(char ch) {
            if (ch == 0) {
                return;
            }
            const char str[2] = {ch, '\0'};
            append_back(str);
        }

        void push_front(char ch) {
            if (ch == 0) {
                return;
            }
            const char str[2] = {ch, '\0'};
            append_front(str);
        }

        void clear() noexcept {
            // free(data);
            printf("CLEAR DELETE, DELETING: %x\n", data);
            delete[] data;
            empty_constructor();
        }

        size_t get_size() const {
            return size;
        }

        size_t get_length() const {
            return length_w_null == 0 ? 0 : length_w_null - 1;
        }

        const char *c_str() const noexcept {
            return string;
        }

        ~String() {
            // free(data);
            printf("DTOR DELETE, DELETING: %x\n", data);
            delete[] data;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& str);
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& str) {
        os << str.string;
        return os;
    }
using namespace std;
int main() {
    String bro;
    char array[] = "eeee;;dlfkjas;j;a;lAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsdjfk";
    bro.clear();
    for (const char &ch : array) {bro.push_front(ch);}
    bro.clear();
    bro.append_back("Let us see!");
    cout << bro << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I added in a few printf() statements to check the addresses, and there is nothing obviously wrong.

A sample output I get is:

```
EMPTY CTOR NEW, MINSIZE: 128, ADDRESS: 9b651920
CLEAR DELETE, DELETING: 9b651920
EMPTY CTOR NEW, MINSIZE: 128, ADDRESS: 9b651920
APPEND FRONT NEW, SIZE: 256, ADDRESS: 9b6519b0
APPEND FRONT DELETE OLD_DATA, DELETING: 9b651920
CLEAR DELETE, DELETING: 9b6519b0
EMPTY CTOR NEW, MINSIZE: 128, ADDRESS: 9b651920
Let us see!
DTOR DELETE, DELETING: 9b651920
```

... before the program crashes.

Compiler: MinGW on Windows.

Comment: Possibly unrelated: `%x` is not the right type to use to print a `char*`. Perhaps `%p`?

Comment: @user4581301 cheers, that is a good point!

Comment: And getting a bit pedantic, `%zu` for the `size_t`s.

Comment: @user4581301 hehe, one can never get too pedantic when it comes to programming :P, thanks again!

Comment: Up in `empty_constructor` we've got `data = new char[MIN_SIZE];`, but ` memset(data, '\0', size);`. If `size != MIN_SIZE` thing's will get ugly.

Comment: Looks like `size = MIN_SIZE;` comes a bit too late in `empty_constructor`

Comment: @user4581301 oh. my. god. I can't believe I missed that. Two days of my life wasted!! Really, I cannot thank you enough for this!!! I have no idea how much longer it would have taken me. It runs absolutely perfectly now. Thank you again!!!!!!!

Comment: Could be more in there. I'm not sure if mingw's g++ supports it yet, but slap `-fsanitize=address,undefined` onto the compiler command line and see if it can give you more diagnostics.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you very much, I will definitely look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user4581301 has been kind enough to check my code and has pointed out the blatant fault in my `empty_constructor()` member function: I use `memset()` to set the values of `size` characters (which can be larger than 128) in my `data` pointer, which only has 128 bytes allocated to it (initially).

By changing `size` to `MIN_SIZE` as the `memset()` argument, everything has been resolved.

Many thanks to user4581301.

I will be accepting this answer as soon as I can to close the question.

Comment: Recommendation: Move all of the variable assignments up to the top of the function . Set `size = MIN_SIZE;` first and then set everything based on `size` rather than `MIN_SIZE` for consistency. Once it's all based on `size`, you'll probably see ways you can eliminate a bit of nearly duplicated code in `constructor` and maybe the `append_` functions.

Comment: @user4581301 that's a great suggestion; it will hopefully also help my code's clarity for my own sake. Working on it as we speak! Thank you for all the time dedicated to this, you are very kind